# If the entire production dataset is known is advance, should I use it when fitting normalization parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, statistics, data-science-model

I found in multiple sources the recommendation not to fit the normalization parameters on the combined train/test dataset when evaluating the model, to prevent data leakage.

I presume this recommendation assumes prediction data would flow to the model online, and the entire data is not known in advance.

Does this recommendation also apply to when the entire data is known in advance?
And even if not, I guess it is possible to refit the model every time we get new data, with normalization parameters acheived from the entire dataset seen until now?

What are the pros and cons of normalizing over the entire dataset before fitting (as opposed to only on the train set)?

Comment: If you know everything, what are you trying to predict?

Answer (score 1):

The point of evaluating your model is to assess how it will perform when it is used on unseen data. Normalizing over the entire dataset causes a data leakage (information coming from the test set). As a result, you will get a biased evaluation of your model.

In any machine learning task, the end goal is to use your model on unseen data to see how much the model has learned and how well it can generalize to unseen data. In that regard, there is no pros for normalizing over the entire dataset, and you should avoid doing so!

Comment: I'm talking about the case where there is no unseen data. The entire dataset is known in advance, but only a part of it is tagged. In this case, normalizing over the entire dataset is really causing leakage? I cannot think of a reason why it would...

Comment: To make this more concrete: lets say I have a database of 10,000 images. Some are annotated and the rest are not. I want to generalize annotations on all the images from the few annotated ones, and I would never need to apply the model on other images from the ones I already have. And even if the need would arise, I can retrain the model again with new recomputed normalization parameters - if I would get any benefit from this, which I'm not sure...

Comment: My task is different from the standard machine learning task - I want to generalize to untagged *seen* data, which I know in advance at train time and I can make use of if necessary...

Comment: If the data in the test set is not labeled, then it is not an actual test set (you can't test the performance of your algorithm), and besides, unseen data is basically the same as unlabeled data. I understand what you mean, just know that the whole issue of data leakage is related to the assessment of your model performance on unlabeled data: if you normalize on the whole dataset, you are likely to get a biased estimate of the model performance.

Comment: Usually in practice, the difference is likely not to be significant, but I would not recommend doing that anyway because you probably won't gain anything in terms of performance by doing it

Comment: I still don't see how it is possible to bias the model by normalizing over the entire data - generally, it would bias because we want to simulate the production case when the entire dataset is not known in advance, so we have unfair advantage in testing as opposed to production - but in my case, I know the full distribution of the data so it does not make sense to me to not incorporate that in the model...

Comment: There are kinds of data where normalization can make a difference, for example when the dataset is small and the features are power-law distributed ,so when we look at part of the data we get low quality normalization parameters.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking that for instance, you may have a big imbalance within your set of unlabeled data (which you cannot know in advance since they are unlabelled), and therefore, normalization could suffer from this imbalance (and in that case, normalization over train set vs entire set would really be different)

Answer (score 1):

If you have all of the data, there is nothing to predict. Only descriptive statistics are being calculated, normalization can be calculated across the entire dataset.

If you do not have all of the data and plan to predict unseen data, calculate the normalization parameters on just the training data split. It is best practice to estimate all parameters on just the training data to see if those parameters are useful to predict unseen data.